# Converting complex value to a normal string

Tags: javascript, c#, json, string

How would I be able to convert this value:

```
string str = ""m1":"DAF","m2":"LF55.220 E16","m3":"Africa Commercial Vehicles","m4":"sdgdf","m5":"gdfg"";
```

To a normal string? I could add more quotations to the front and back but I get the same errors.

I'm getting errors like the following:

```
; expected
} expected
```

It seems simple enough but I can't figure out how to convert it to a string.

EDIT:

This is another example that I get from the app. The value is an object.

```
Object {1: "DAF", 2: "FA LF55.220 E15", 3: "Barloworld Isuzu Trucks City Deep", 4: "dsfsdfsdfdsfsddsfdsfdsf", 5: "fsdfdsfdsdsfdsfdsfdsfds", 6: "dsfdsfdsfdsfdfdssddsf", 7: "dsfsddsfdfdssdfsdfdsf", 8: "sfsdfdsfdsdfdsfsdfsfd", 9: "sdfdsfsdsdsdfdsfdsfds", 10: "Hankook", 11: "11", 12: Object, 13: "Yes", 14: "Repair", 15: "Yes", 16: "Yes", 17: "Yes", 18: "Yes", 19: "Yes", 20: "Yes", 21: "Yes", 22: "Yes", 23: "Yes", 24: "Yes", 25: "Yes", 26: "Yes", 27: "Yes", 28: "Yes", 29: "Yes", 30: "Yes", 31: "Yes", 32: "Yes", 33: "Yes", 34: "Yes", 35: "Yes", 36: "Yes", 37: "Yes", 38: "Yes", 39: "Yes", 40: "Yes", 41: "Yes", 42: "Yes", 43: "Yes", 44: "Yes", 45: "df sfsdfsdfdfsdf d fsf sdf sdfsd fsdf sdf", 46: "1"}
```

This is what the value lookslike in the console log.

EDIT 2: Here is the method. It's from another coder and as it's coded in javascript.

```
$scope.postData = {
    m1 : M1.Name,
    m2 : M2.Name, 
    m3 : M3.Name, 
    m4 : M4, 
    m5 : M5, 
    ...   
};


var post = new Post($scope.postData);
  post.$save(function(postObject) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(postObject));
  });

.factory('Post', function($resource) {
    console.log('factory');
 return $resource('http://localhost:53101/Service.svc/BOB');//addchecklist 
});
```

EDIT 3: This is the c# method and the WCF OperationContract

```
   public string BOB(Stream streamdata)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);
        string res = reader.ReadToEnd();

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(res);
        }
        sb.Replace(":", "|").Replace(",", "|").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");

        string[] arData = sb.ToString().Split('|');
        string a = arData[0];
        string b = arData[1];
        string c = arData[2];
        string d = arData[3];
        string e = arData[4];
        string f = arData[5];
        string g = arData[6];
        string h = arData[7];
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        return "Received: " + res;
    }

 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/BOB", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        string BOB(Stream streamdata);
```

Comment: can you provide the raw data you receive from mobile app?

Comment: please show which is variable/ value that you want to convert to string. I am guessing all you need is just concatenate them with `+`

Comment: @CareTaker22 - cool :) now we can see the context. So now what is your question? You get this javascript object in the C# and what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to convert this whole object into a string in c#, but the values within my object are to complex to convert it into a string. I need to convert it to a string so that I can split all the values within my string and also remove unwanted commas and quotation marks :)

Comment: @CareTaker22- So can you show the C# code that receives this message?

Comment: I've updated the answer again

Comment: The other programmer figured it out. Thank you for your input Gilad Green. No more help is needed. Sorry for wasting your time :p

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is to escape `"` with `\"`.

```
string str = "\"m1\":\"DAF\",\"m2\":\"LF55.220 E16\",\"m3\":\"Africa Commercial Vehicles\",\"m4\":\"sdgdf\",\"m5\":\"gdfg\"";
```

Comment: The problem is that I get the value directly from a mobile app and I need to save that value to a string. I can't escape with the method above beacause I cant get the value into a string in the first place :(

Comment: @CareTaker22 - ya but can you show the code that brings you that? It looks like a JSON. Please see how to be more clear with what you need

Comment: Sorry for posting the question so poorly, but I was in a hurry to get finish some other work. The code is done in javascript and sent to a wcf service.